# I'm trying to create a looping validation method that tests data type and range

Tags: java, loops, validation, methods

I'm new to java and I'm tinkering with my code and decided to create an input validation method, my problem is how am I going to loop the input through the validations.

First I decided to take the input as string to do a try/catch with a double, no problem with that, now I need to test the input if it's in the range of 0-100. Of course I wanted to check if the user will type in a double in the "range check". What I wrote somewhat worked but when the input passed the data type validation but not the range check, it will still return the first double, whatever I typed next.

```
public static double check(String n){
        boolean done = false;
        double i=0.0;
        Scanner beep = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!done) {
            try { 
                i = Double.parseDouble(n);
                done = true;   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Please input a valid grade (0-100): ");
                n = beep.nextLine();
            }
        }
        double b = rangetest(i);
        return b;
    }

    public static double rangetest (double n){
        if (n > 100 || n < 0){
            System.out.print("0-100 only ");
            Scanner beep = new Scanner(System.in);
            check(beep.next());
        }
        return n;

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner beep = new Scanner(System.in);
        double ave = 0.0;
        int rounded;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Input grade number " + i + " : ");
            ave += rangetest(check(beep.next()));
        }
        ave /= 5;
        rounded = (int)Math.round(ave);
}
```

Is there any easier methods or workarounds? Or am I doing it all wrong? Cheers!

Comment: `n > 0 && n < 100` - for "is within range" style check or `n < 0 || n > 100` for "is outside of range" style check

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there a difference if I used the "within range"? How should I implement this? Thanks!

Comment: It will depend on "how" you want to handle it, for example, if "is within range" -> Handle positive workflow

Comment: Be aware of `beep.next()`, as this will leave a dangling new line in the input buffer, which can cause issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer About the `beep.next()`, I thought closing this will close the input stream altogether and will be unusable in the process?

Comment: You don't want to close `System.in` and the dangling new line can cause issues with you then use things like `nextDouble`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of `Scanner#next`, this can leave a dangling new line character in the buffer which can mess with your workflows, however, the core issue is with your `rangetest`

```
public static double rangetest (double n){
    if (n > 100 || n < 0){
        System.out.print("0-100 only ");
        Scanner beep = new Scanner(System.in);
        check(beep.next());
    }
    return n;

}
```

Here, if the value is not within the specified range, you're calling `check` again, but you're ignoring the result, so you end up returning the original value of `n`

It would seem that instead, you want to do...

```
n = rangetest(check(beep.next()))
```

within the `if` block.

You could accomplish something similar using `do-while` loops, for example...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double value = getDoubleWithinRange(scanner, "Make me an offer ([X] to exit): ", "That's not a reasonable offer", "X", 0, 100, "Value is not within a valid range (0-100)");
        if (value != null) {
            System.out.println("You mad an offer of " + value);
        }
    }

    public static Double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner input, String prompt, String errorMessage, String exitValue, double min, double max, String rangeErrorMessage) {
        boolean done = false;
        Double value = null;
        do {
            value = getDouble(input, prompt, errorMessage, exitValue);
            if (value != null) {
                if (isWithinRange(value, 0, 100)) {
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    beep();
                    System.out.println(rangeErrorMessage);
                }
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        } while (!done);
        return value;
    }

    public static void beep() {
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    public static boolean isWithinRange(double value, double min, double max) {
        return value >= min && value <= max;
    }

    public static Double getDouble(Scanner input, String prompt, String errorMessage, String exitValue) {
        Double value = null;
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String nextLine = input.nextLine();
            Scanner parser = new Scanner(nextLine);
            if (parser.hasNextDouble()) {
                value = parser.nextDouble();
            } else if (nextLine.equals(exitValue)) {
                exit = true;
            } else {
                beep();
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
            }
        } while (!(value != null || exit));
        return value;
    }

}
```

*nb: I have a exit condition available, you don't need it, but it's nice as a demonstration*

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for the answer @MadProgrammer ! I will see for myself if I can understand my problem and your solution, I'll check back with an update!

Answer (score 0):

I fashioned myself a function from @MadProgrammer's code (Thanks man!), this somehow works a wee bit simpler.

```
public static double getValue() {
    Scanner beep = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag = true;
    double value=0.0;
    while(flag==true){
        if(beep.hasNextDouble()){
            value = beep.nextDouble();
            if(value>=0&&value<=100){  
                flag=false;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("Invalid input, 0-100 only: ");
                beep.nextLine();
            } 
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("That's not a numerical value, try again: ");
            beep.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Feel free to comment, make a correction and/or suggest anything that would make this better.